# Mailx with at command

Tags: bash, mailx, at-job

I am trying to send a mail with at command, but the mail is getting delivered instantly, instead it should send the mail as per the time provided in at command. Below is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=`date +%Y%m%d`
echo 'Please enter the User-Name:'
read name
echo 'No. of days access is required - number only'
read NumberofDays

echo "Root access revoked for $name" | mailx -s "root access revoked for $name on $TODAY" xyz@example.com| at now + $NumberofDays
```

Comment: I guess your usage of `at` command here is wrong.As per your last line in the script, the message of `echo` will be piped to the `mailx` command first and then to `at`, that's why the mail is being delivered first and `at` command is ignored.

Comment: Read [man at(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at), Check the usage of `-f` and `-m` with `at` command.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the difference between these two statements:

- pipe the output of a command to `at`
- pipe a command text to execute to `at`

The script you showed does the first, and you want to do the second:

```
cat << EOF | at "now + $NumberofDays days"
echo "Root access revoked for $name" | \
mailx -s "root access revoked for $name on $TODAY" xyz@example.com
EOF
```

I also added "days" after `$NumberofDays` (thanks [@User123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8001873/user123)!) in the `at` command's arguments,
otherwise it's not correct syntax for `at`.

Comment: I guess `days` should be added after the variable:`$NumberofDays` in `at` command, like: `at "now + $NumberofDays days"` or else it'll give error.

Comment: @User123 - Actually I am providing the input manually in minutes as well to check the script, that's why I kept it as it is.